# xmlhttp.onreadystatechange firing only once in asynchronous call

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest

Here is my js code

```
function makeAsynchronousPostHttpCall(url, params, callback) {
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open("POST", url, true); // false for synchronous request
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xmlHttp.send(params);
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = callback(xmlHttp);
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
}

function fooBar() {
    var url = foo;
    var config = bar;
    var params = "config=" + config;
    var callback = (xmlHttp) => {
        console.log(xmlHttp.readyState);
        if(xmlHttp.readyState == 1){
            document.getElementById('progress').innerHTML = 'Request in Progress For '+ config;
            document.getElementById('completedMessage').innerHTML = "";
        }
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById('progress').innerHTML = 'Request Completed For '+ config;
            document.getElementById('completedMessage').innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    makeAsynchronousPostHttpCall(url, params, callback);

}
```

Everything w.r.t request and response are working fine. The request is succesfull and I get expected response. But the problem is my "xmlHttp.onreadystatechange" callback is fired only once. i.e in console log I could find only "1". But the same case works fine when I use synchronous call. My page is getting updated with my completed message. But with Asynchronous call the page is getting updated with "Request in Progress For bar", but once the request is completed I dont see any further changes in my page.

Is there any catch while working with asynchronous call ?

Thanks !!

Comment: `.onreadystatechange` needs to be a function - you're not setting it to be a function ... `xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = () => callback(xmlHttp);`

Comment: @JaromandaX, I am sorry that I'm not getting you. I have assigned a function to var 'callback' and assigned it to xhr.onreadystatechange. what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: `xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = callback(xmlHttp);` calls `callback(xmlHttp)` **immediately** and assigns the value returned by that function to `xmlHttp.onreadystatechange` ... there's a difference between calling a function and (which is what you are doing) and referencing a function to assign to whatever (which is what you NEED to do)

Comment: example `var a = Math.random();`  executes `Math.random()` immediately - no different to what you're doing

Comment: @JaromandaX, Yes, that is a mistake ... Thanks

Comment: @JaromandaX, but I wonder how it worked well for synchronous call .

Comment: synchronous call is synchronous ... by the time you call `callback(xmlHttp)` the request has been fully fulfilled